# Escape string input to sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having some problems with replacing a string in a file using sed with a string that contains newlines. The following will fail completely. I assume I've got to escape the replace_with string, but I can't work out how, or if this is even the best way to do it. Any help would be appreciated

```
REPLACE_WITH="Blah
 de
 blah."

sed -i "s/TO_REPLACE/$REPLACE_WITH/g" file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs "double escaping", but the escape characters need to get to the sed's "s" command so they have to be escaped from the bash shell too. ("Triple escaping" ?)

```
REPLACE_WITH="Blah\\
de\\
blah."

sed -i "s/TO_REPLACE/$REPLACE_WITH/g" file
```

Bash decodes the "\\" into a single "\" and puts a single '\' into the send command which the sed command then interprets as a '\{newline}' which is takes to mean a newline that doesn't end the command.

If you had just one '\' at the end of each line bash would see the '\{newline}' which it would take as a 'nothing' ie: the newline and backslash are completely removed.

Basic rule for bash-sed-awk ... if your backslashes aren't working try doubling them ... again.

Comment: Unfortunately, that produces the following once sed has run (with the correct line breaks of course) - 

REPLACE_WITH="Blah\ de\ blah."

Comment: Yes, it does; the backslashes in the string are required to make a multiline s/// command in the sed script. If you want to quote a plain string into a sufficiently quoted string to modify the "file" you probably need an extra sed command ... is that what you're after ?

Comment: Just realised I've been testing the wrong script. Will try again now sorry :(

Comment: Finally got around to testing it with the right script, and it works thank you :)